# User to close element can't click outside of it becouse it's open over other element that is SVG diagram

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I have datepicker that is showing when I want to choose daterange - it's shared component and I thought it was working fine until I check it at the view that contains big SVG diagram - the datepicker when is open is over that diagram.

Libraries:
1) Daterangepicker - bootstrap-datepicker (https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
2) Diagram - https://d3js.org/

Screenshots:

1) [Opened datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sylb4.jpg)
2) [Checked SVG element in Chrome DEV Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O7w9.jpg)

Code when I call diagram:

```
<div class="ibox float-e-margins page-ibox">
    <div class="ibox-title">
        <div style="display: inline-block">
            <cb-toolbar [openDbModalFn]="openDatabaseModal"></cb-toolbar>
        </div>
        <iboxtools [closable]="false" [float]="'clear'"></iboxtools>
    </div>
    <div class="ibox-content" id="ifs-ibox-content">
        <div id="no-data-wrapper">

            <div id="no-data-overlay">
                <!-- <%=st.get("FILTERS_RETURNED_NO_DATA") %> -->
                {{ "FILTERS_RETURNED_NO_DATA" | translate }}
            </div>
            <cb-chord-diagram></cb-chord-diagram>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And code for datepickers:

```
<div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
<input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" id="dateFrom" autocomplete="off"/>
<span class="input-group-addon">{{translationService.translate("TO_LOWERCASE")}}</span>
<input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" id="dateTo" autocomplete="off"/>
```

What I already tried to do that was that I checked component that build diagram to find there method event.stopPropagation() but it's not there. I have no other ideas what can be wrong.

Comment: Solution 1: In the case you don't need to click the SVG diagram  add `pointer-events:none` in the css for the diagram.  Solution 2: if Solution 1 didn't work for some reason move the data picker above the diagram in the svg. If none of these solutions works for you, please consider adding the code for a _working example_

Comment: I did something like this and it works, but I don't know is made with good practices:

            $('#svg4').click( () => {
            $('#dateFrom').datepicker('hide');
            $('#dateTo').datepicker('hide');
        });